# How to Check if the Two Turtles are on the Same Y Coordinate in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

I am working on a NetLogo project and I want my pupil turtles to move straight until they come to be on the same Y coordinate as their relevant link neighbour and from there move towards them (the link neighbour).

Note that each pupil has only one link neighbour.

This is the code that I have come up with,

```
to go
  ask pupils [
    let target one-of link-neighbors 
    ifelse [ycor] of myself != [ycor] of target
      [
        set heading 0
        fd 1
      ]
      [
        face target
        fd 1      
      ] 
  ]
  tick
end
```

This does not work, the turtles keep moving straight. Can someone please help. I just want the turtles to get to their link neighbours, but there are walls that they must avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that ycor is a decimal value. So, For example turtle 1 may be on 3.2 and turtle 2 may be on 3.3.

Instead, I think you want to use turtles-here.

```
to go
  ask pupils [
    let target one-of link-neighbors 
    ifelse member? target turtles-here
      [set heading 0]
      [face target] 
      fd 1
  ]
  tick
end
```

On a side note, how many link-neighbors does each target have? My concern is that `let target one-of link-neighbors` will reset the target each tick.

Comment: This is great, it works for me! Thank you!
Each pupil has only one link-neighbor. They are randomly assigned, so that problem does not affect us.